# Remove the price logic of woocommerce with my custom one, how?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a website with lots of rules applied on the price and all can't be achieved with the facilities available within the woocommerece.

Since the site is already designed and developed in woocommerce, I can't change it even.

Please advice me the how can I change the entire price logic of woocommerce to my custom logic. And also let me know that is it advisable or not?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well its not advisable to change the price logic unless you are pretty good in creating plugins for woocommerce. but woocommerce already know that there are not many options with the pricing, so they have created a plugin just for this purpose and it fulfills the need of 90% of the users. It is a bit expensive but depending on the quality of the code and support its worth it. Or if you are tight on budget you can use the one from codecanyon which is less than quater the price.
http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-dynamic-pricing-discounts/7119279

woocommerce-dynamic-pricing-discounts is not as good as the one from woocommerce but it does its job pretty well.

Comment: For reference: [Dynamic Pricing](https://www.woothemes.com/products/dynamic-pricing)

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to extends woocommerce class WC_Cart in theme and modify

class Custom_WC_Cart extends WC_Cart {

      public function calculate_totals() {

      /**
       * Modify in This function.
       */
      }

if you are extends this functionality may be change 2 or 3 places change.
```

1) create global custom cart obj.
2) change reorder functionality.

Comment: Is there any hooks or action / filter I can use instead of doing this?